# Best Practices for Multi-User Web Application on Top of Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on a variety of ML heavy applications in Apache Spark and have an eye toward production.  What would be the best approaches to building an interactive multiuser web application directly on top of Apache Spark?

Comment: What do you envision spark being used for?  Did you want to use Spark to return data to the webapp, like a query on a dataset.  Or did you want users to beable to reuse RDDs?  Can you add more details to what you want to do?

Comment: Hello Joe-Yes, I am interested in the first case you mention.  Basically, planning on building an app that allows for querying of the data, visualizing subsets in bokeh, and perhaps eventually a GUI for applying some methods.  Just trying to conceive the quirks of using Spark as a backend for this role.  Any advice to keep in mind would be great!

Comment: Pylander, I probably wouldn't use Spark as a backend for doing this.  Spark is fast, but not fast enough for near real time.  The fastest spark jobs can take time measured in seconds.  Id suggest you go a more traditional route using a db to deliver data to your app. Use Spark to do some of the processing periodically to update those databases.  If you don't mind users waiting 15+s for results, or have a situation where on demand model training is required, you could use Spark.  If you just need to run bits of data through a model, I'd shoot for python and use Spark for model building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at doing something similar for the analysts at my company. It would probably be best to look at something like [Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/spark/java) before deciding to roll your own.

> Livy is an open source REST interface for interacting with Spark from anywhere. It supports executing snippets of code or programs in a Spark context that runs locally or in YARN.

Features include:

> - Interactive Scala, Python and R shells
> - Batch submissions in Scala, Java, Python
> - Multi users can share the same server (impersonation support)
> - Can be used for submitting jobs from anywhere with REST
> - Does not require any code change to your programs

I don't know how much stock I'd put in the that last bullet, but this is what's in their docs.

You could build a web interface to make it easier to post snippets to the jobserver, or write a little python script using requests to send jobs as files a-la spark-submit.

Other things to look into if you do decide to develop this idea further is how to share resources within a running spark application. The [Fair Scheduler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) is something that would make a lot of sense in that situation.

> Under fair sharing, Spark assigns tasks between jobs in a “round robin” fashion, so that all jobs get a roughly equal share of cluster resources. This means that short jobs submitted while a long job is running can start receiving resources right away and still get good response times, without waiting for the long job to finish. This mode is best for multi-user settings.

Comment: Wow, this is very insightful stuff!  I was unfamiliar with Livy or Fair Scheduler.

Comment: @dayman firstly +1 for your username.  Secondly, are you familiar with spark job server and how does it compare to livy?  https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver